# How to ensure each tick is labelled?

Tags: highcharts

I have a basic bar chart for which every second bar is labelled:

[image]

I guess that this is because Highcharts decided that the chart would be otherwise too crowded.

**I would like, however, to make sure that each bar has its label. How can I achieve this?**

The closest I found is [`overflow`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.overflow) (set to `"allow"`) and [`step`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step) (set to `1`). This does not help, though:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            step: 1,
            overflow: "allow"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Everything looks fine in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bv4c5aLo/)

Comment: Could you send an online example with your data (jsfiddle)?